# After update and saving the model to store without connecting backend gives error

Tags: json, ember.js

I am trying to update my mode just only store without connecting backend. after it's done successfully I will retrive the updated model using it's id.

for that, I am trying to push my model to store ( updating the existing model in store ) but getting error.

any one hlpe me?

here is my code :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {

    if(this.store.hasRecordForId('card-list', params.id)){
        return this.store.peekRecord('card-list', params.id );//getting
    }
  },
  actions:{
    formValidateBeforeNext:function(){

        var model = this.controllerFor(this.routeName).get('model');
        var modelId = this.controllerFor(this.routeName).get('model').get("id");
        var oneTimeFee = this.controllerFor(this.routeName).get('model').get("oneTimeFee");
        var monthlyInstalmentAmount = this.controllerFor(this.routeName).get('model').get("monthlyInstalmentAmount");

        console.log( "model would be:-" , JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model)) );

        this.store.push(JSON.parse(model));//updating without connect to backend,but throws error

        console.log( "store data", this.store.peekRecord('card-list', modelId ) )

        this.transitionTo('cs2i.balance.balanceReview', {id:modelId});

    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what serializer you want to use. I'm assuming you're using the default JSONSerializer. If that's the case, here's how you have to push the data into the store.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        if(this.store.hasRecordForId('card-list', params.id)){
           return this.store.peekRecord('card-list', params.id );//getting
        }
    },
    actions:{
        formValidateBeforeNext:function(){
            var modelData = { //creating a sample data for testing purpose. You can fetch the data as above from your example
                id:1,
                type:"card-list",
                attributes:{
                    oneTimeFee:1000,
                    testPayment:2000
                }
             }

          console.log( "model would be:-" , JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(modelData)) );

          this.store.push({
              data: modelData
          });//updating without connect to backend,but throws error

          console.log( "store data", this.store.peekRecord('card-list', 1 ) )

          this.transitionTo('cs2i.balance.balanceReview', {id:modelId});
        }
     }
});
```

Even if it is RestSerializer all you have to do is use this.store.pushPayload and use model name ("cardList") as the key instead of data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: for my case I am keep getting error either way as : `Expected an object in the 'data' property in a call to 'push' for undefined, but was instance
Error` - can you help me to sort this out?

Comment: can you show me what does your model object look like before doing a push to the store. @3gwebtrain

Comment: I used `store.push(store.normalize('person', data));` it works for me. But when I go to next page, the model is not called.

Comment: Any Idea to fix that?

Comment: You should not call store.normalize explicitly since that is called automatically when you make a network request. May be that could be a issue. Leaving that aside, what do you mean by next page? you mean another route? If you're transitioning to another route, then are you able to see the data present in the ember data inspector?

Comment: My requirements is to update in store and retrieve in next page without making backend call

Comment: I've created a twiddle for you. Basically, there is a home route and inside that there is a page1 route. When you click on button transition to next route happens and the model method will peek the results from the store. For testing purpose, I'm displaying the values from the store on the handlebars file. Let me know if you've issues in understanding the twiddle

https://ember-twiddle.com/695178314f397b9406037008b58694d5?openFiles=templates.home

Comment: Yes you are closely done, but my case parent has 2 sub page first page edits/updates the model and keeps in store and second page displays the model from store. All happens without calling backend other than initial call by parent route

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151740/discussion-between-ios-dev-and-3gwebtrain).

Comment: I am out of office, through mobile I am not able to chat

Comment: Isn't it the same thing happening in the twiddle I provided.
Lets consider home route in the twiddle as sub page no.1 and page1 in the twiddle as sub page no.2 as per your requirements. So, home route updates/pushes the data to the store and page1 route retrieves the data from the store

Comment: Home page lists all model, user click on one of the model, page 1 gets model by I'd, and Save to store, and transaction to page 2, page 2 getting updated model by I'd again and show for review